# fusion tables map - how to display the infowindows further down on the google map?

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I have made a map using multiple layers of fusion tables, some of it with the help last year of members on this forum (thank you!)

Now I am redesigning it with an overhang above the top of the map, but the result is that the infowindows appear with their tops hidden underneath the overhang.

What I want to do is push the infowindows down below the overhang. Here are a few things I've tried, that didn't work:

** z-index in the css
** a border-top or margin-top in the css for the .googft-info-window
** and this line in the JS:

```
                  pixelOffset: e.pixelOffset (100,100)
```

which only results in the absence of the infowindow when a marker/polygon is clicked.

I think the solution is probably in the pixelOffset, but I am no programmer and can't figure out how to write the code.

Here is a very stripped-down version of my project (just two of the eight layers) which I think illustrates the problem:

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>layer test parklotproject</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.651541,-79.371006),
          zoom: 9,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        // Initialize the first layer
       var firstLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'Location',
            from: '1bkYbC7wZRrvWELw96g3mcwa9mGwSI-auSu9wP70'
          },
          map: map,
          suppressInfoWindows: true
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(firstLayer, 'click', function(e) {
          windowControl(e, infoWindow, map);
        });

        // Initialize the second layer
        var secondLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'Location',
            from: '1Zw6q0HhqWPtorfs-7FmLzP_mabUz326W_OuCTQE'
          },
          map: map,
          suppressInfoWindows: true
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(secondLayer, 'click', function(e) {
          windowControl(e, infoWindow, map);
        });
      }

      // Open the info window at the clicked location
      function windowControl(e, infoWindow, map) {
        infoWindow.setOptions({
          content: e.infoWindowHtml,
          position: e.latLng,
          pixelOffset: e.pixelOffset
        });
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
BODY { 
margin-top : 0px; 
margin-left : 20px; 
background-color : #ffffff; 
} 
body, td, th { 
letter-spacing : 1px; 
line-height : 140%; 
font-family : Verdana, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size : 13px; 
} 
html {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
#welcomecontrols {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: .8;
background-color : #ffffff;     }
#map-canvas{
    top:10px;
    position:absolute;
    clear:none;
    z-index:1;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 600px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 96%;
} 
.googft-info-window{
    background-color:white;
    text-align:left;
    z-index: 1000;   
    height:400px; width:590px; overflow: auto;
}
</style>     
</head>
<body> 
<div  id="welcomecontrols">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td valign="bottom">
<h1><span style="color:#333333; font-size:15px;">Welcome to</span><br>
<span style="letter-spacing:2px; color:#D2691E; font-size:22px;"><b>The Toronto Park Lot Project</b></span></h1>
</td>
<td width="10" align="right" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" valign="top">
<p><b>an exploration of the earliest days of the TOWN OF YORK, founded 1793 by <nobr>John Graves Simcoe,</nobr> first Lieutenant-Governor of Upper Canada</b><br>
<i>(The Town of York was incorporated 1834 as the City of Toronto.)</i><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?
Thank you.
Wendy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) with a height equal to the height of the overhang to the TOP-controls of the map.

The API usually will try to place the `infoWindow` into a position where it will not be covered by a control(when possible)

**Demo:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/doktormolle/EezcR/show/
**Source:** http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/EezcR/